# UFW port open, netstat does not show it

Tags: networking, firewall, ufw, netstat

the result of `ufw status`

is

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
30333                      ALLOW       Anywhere
8200                       ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
8200/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
30333 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8200 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8200/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

However `netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "` returns

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.10:8080         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.10:8080         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.100.1:8080        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

I was expecting 0.0.0.0:8200 to be listened on... How can I achieve that ? I'm obviously missing something here...

Comment: You must have a server program listening to port 8200 before `netstat` sees the port. Also `sudo lsof -i` will give more info.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to mention that indeed I do have a docker container with port 8200 that is listening. In fact, when make a GET on it with telnet from the host, I do have a 200 HTTP response. But from the outside, I don't. I'll try lsof command and report back.

Answer (score 0):

since you want to check the port of 8200 u can use the command this command `sudo netstat -ano -p tcp |grep "8200"`

or you grep yours with the port number you are looking for  `sudo netstat -an | grep "8200 "`